# Extract numeric info from text

Tags: regex, pcre, autoit

I need to extract numeric info from text.

```
Ready

State: CTYG  Work Request #: 2880087 General

Job Address

Contact

Work Request Search
```

My code :

```
$Text = WinGetText("[ACTIVE]")
Sleep(4000)
$Value = StringSplit($Text, @CRLF)
MsgBox(0, "Hello", $Value, 10) ;---1st message box
Sleep(4000)

For $i = 1 To $Value[0]

    If StringRegExp($Value[$i], "[0-9][^:alpha:]") Then

        MsgBox(0, "Hello1", $Value[$i], 5) ;---2nd message box
        Sleep(200)
        $newWR = $Value[$i]
        MsgBox(0, "Hello2", $newWR, 10)
        ConsoleWrite($newWR) ;---3rd message box

    EndIf

Next
```

1st `MsgBox()` shows nothing. The 2nd and 3rd show `State: CTYG  Work Request #: 2880087 General`. But I don't need the entire line, I just want `2880087`.

Comment: I have been able to do it like below :

    $Text=WinGetText("[ACTIVE]")

 sleep(40)

 $Value=StringMid($Text,38,8)


This gives me the number 2880087 

But this is just hard coded coding and i wanted to know if there are ways to pinpoint the location of 2880087 without any hard-coding.

Comment: your first MsgBox doesn't show you anything, because `$Value` is an array, not a string. You should use `_ArrayDisplay` instead.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? This will delete everything but numbers.

```
$str = "State: CTYG Work Request #: 2880087 General"
ConsoleWrite(StringRegExpReplace($str, '\D', '') & @CRLF)
```

Answer (score -1):

> … *i just want 2880087* …

Example using regular expression `State: .+ #: (\d+)` :

```
#include <StringConstants.au3>; StringRegExp()
#include <Array.au3>

Global Const $g_sText   = 'Ready' & @CRLF & @CRLF _
                        & 'State: CTYG Work Request #: 2880087 General' & @CRLF & @CRLF _
                        & 'Job Address' & @CRLF & @CRLF _
                        & 'Contact' & @CRLF & @CRLF _
                        & 'Work Request Search'
Global Const $g_sRegEx  = 'State: .+ #: (\d+)'
Global Const $g_aResult = StringRegExp($g_sText, $g_sRegEx, $STR_REGEXPARRAYMATCH)

ConsoleWrite($g_sText & @CRLF)
_ArrayDisplay($g_aResult)
```

Stores `2880087` to `$g_aResult[0]`.